# what's the relationship between `system.diagnostics.trace` and nlog/log4net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nlog

I am learning asp.net web API (framework, not core). generally, I will use `system.diagnostics.trace` to write logs. but a bro suggests to use Nlog.

is `Nlog/log4net` a wrapper of `system.diagnostics.trace`? will it override the built-in behavior of `system.diagnostics.trace`? And what are `Microsoft Extension Logging` and `NLog.Extensions.Logging`?

if I use Nlog, will the system log from `.Net framework` also turn to `Nlog` target?

I am confused with above concepts, can you help me?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776691/193178

Answer (score 0):

[NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging) and [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/) is for Microsoft Extension Logging in ASP.NET Core.

The nice thing about `system.diagnostics.trace` is that it doesn't add any extra dependencies.

The nice thing about NLog/log4net/Serilog is that they make it easy to redirect logging-output to many different targets (file / console / database / email / etc.) and provides many options for how configure the layout-format of the output (json / csv / plain-text).

Forexample [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web/) for ASP.NET Classic provides [extensions to NLog](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web) for easy capture context of the web-request. Ex. [${aspnet-request-url}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetRequest-Url-Layout-Renderer)